# Next.js TypeScript Error: You do not have the required packages installed

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am currently building out a basic nextjs website with the help of their handy typescript starter. Everything has been running smooth while developing using `yarn dev` until about 20 minutes ago, when I started randomly getting an error message any time I try to run `yarn dev`.

This is the error ouput:

```
It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed.

Please install @types/react by running:

        yarn add --dev @types/react
```

This just randomly started happening with no changes made to the codebase. I've tried wiping node_modules completely and reinstalling, and even tried cleaning the yarn cache. The dependency `"@types/react": "^18.0.2"` is included correctly in my package.json's `devDependencies` object, so I am totally clueless on how to fix this.

P.S. I found an existing issue posted about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682961/asked-to-install-typescript-when-already-installed-when-building-docker-image), but it is not related to my issue at all, as it pertains to Docker. All I am doing is running next.js locally on my laptop, it is not running in production anywhere.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue after creating a new project with `npx create-next-app@latest --ts` this morning.

Comment: @LeeHarrison Check out the answer that I just accepted. This should work for you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the `@types/react` package itself, which was just updated to 18.0.2 the morning that you ran into this problem. Rolling back to 18.0.1 appears to work.

Update: This is not an issue with `@types/react 18.0.4` which is used in the current `create-next-app` as of yesterday. Just a short term annoyance.

Comment: man just update to 18.0.3, its working

Comment: @saulpalv Updating to 18.0.3 did nothing to fix the problem.

Comment: Rolling back to 18.0.1 worked for me.

Comment: I'll leave this as the accepted answer for now, but if you are able to, I'd recommend you just follow tinokaartovuori's answer below, as it won't require you to roll back any specific packages.

Comment: @dan-zuzevich sorry, it was something else then, however we now have 18.0.4

Comment: Same problem with version 18.0.28. I rolled back to 18.0.1 for it to work.

Answer (score 57):

I had the same problem. Solved by updating Next.js and React.

Updating next.js

```
npm install next@latest
```

Updating react version in the next.js app:

```
npm upgrade react@latest react-dom@latest
```

Source:
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/how+to+update+next+js+version

Comment: Upgrading Next did it for me (from `12.1` to `12.2.5`). Didn't need to touch `react`.

Comment: @FernandoRojo Hrm, I wonder why this works

Comment: Btw you should only use `npm upgrade react react-dom` else "Update arguments must only contain package names" error comes

Answer (score 1):

The package `create-next-app` has been updated!

Use: `npx create-next-app@latest my-app --typescript`

This works for me now ;)