# It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

There are two similar question asked before: [Q-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71842787/next-js-typescript-error-you-do-not-have-the-required-packages-installed) and [Q-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843307/next-js-is-not-recognizing-types-react)

However, my situation is different. I had a working project with those

```
"dependencies": {,
  "next": "10.2.3",
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "17.0.2",
  "swr": "^0.5.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^17.0.9",
  "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
  "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
  "postcss": "^8.3.5",
  "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
  "postcss-nesting": "^8.0.1",
  "prettier": "^2.3.1",
  "tailwindcss": "^2.1.4",
  "typescript": "^4.3.2"
}
```

I upgraded next.js to `^12.2.2`, so react and react-dom have to be upgraded to version 18. but this caused me too many bugs so I decided to get back to using old dependencies. I already saved the prior `package.json` and just copied the complete `package.json`, delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, cleared the cache `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm install`. I expected project work but it gave me this error:

```
It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed.

Please install @types/react by running:

        npm install --save-dev @types/react

If you are not trying to use TypeScript, please remove the tsconfig.json file from your package root (and any TypeScript files in your pages directory).
```

I tried to set `"@types/react": "^17.0.2"` but still get an error. This is not a package version issue

I used node version 16, 18 and 19 but same error

Comment: Instead of `^1.2.3` for dependencies, you can try using it without `^` sign. That might help.