# Dockerizing Nextjs with typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, docker, next.js

I'm trying to build a Docker Image of my Nextjs frontend(React) application for production and am currently stuck at typescript integration.

Here's the Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:14-alpine3.14 as deps

RUN apk add --no-cache tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
EXPOSE 4500
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

RUN mkdir /app && chown -R node:node /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --production && npm cache clean --force

FROM node:14-alpine3.14 as build
RUN mkdir /app && chown -R node:node /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY --chown=node:node . ./
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN npm run build


FROM node:14-alpine3.14 as prod
RUN mkdir /app && chown -R node:node /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=7777
COPY --from=build /app ./
USER node
CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]
```

Now this results in an error:

```
It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed.
```

Basically since I'm doing npm ci --production it doesn't install devDependencies where typescript is.

After searching I've arrived at few solutions.

Solution 1: The first one is to add typescript to dependencies. Though it is advised that since typescript is only devDependency it should not be in normal dependencies.

Solution 2: Adding typescript via `npm install`. Basically same as solution 1. I modified the Dockerfile as:

```
FROM node:14-alpine3.14 as deps

COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --production && npm cache clean --force

# Added typescript and node types here
RUN npm install --save-dev typescript @types/node
```

In this case the total image size becomes: 981.58 MB.

Solution 3: Doing simple `npm install` instead of `npm ci --production`.

```
FROM node:14-alpine3.14 as deps

COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock.json ./

# Simple npm install
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force
```

In this case I end installing all devDependencies also. In this case the total image size is: 537.32 MB.

Now I have few questions regarding this.

Question 1: Why does adding typescript via `npm install --save-dev typescript @types/node` in Solution 2 results in bigger file size compared to Solution 3 where we install all the dependencies?

Question 2: If in Solution 3 I do `npm ci` instead of `npm install` the total image size comes out to be 972.59 MB. Why does using `npm ci` increase the image size. Shouldn't it just install exact packages based on package-lock.json.

Question 3: I looked at discussion [Asked to install Typescript when already installed when building Docker image.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682961/asked-to-install-typescript-when-already-installed-when-building-docker-image)

It suggested a solution with multi-staged build like this.

```
FROM gcr.io/companyX/companyX-node-base:12-alpine AS build

# Copy in only the parts needed to install dependencies
# (This avoids rebuilds if the package.json hasn’t changed)
COPY package.json package.lock .

# Install dependencies (including dev dependencies)
RUN npm install

# Copy in the rest of the project
# (include node_modules in a .dockerignore file)
COPY . .

# Build the project
RUN npm run build

# Second stage: runtime
FROM gcr.io/companyX/companyX-node-base:12-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Again get dependencies, but this time only install
# runtime dependencies
COPY package.json package.lock .
RUN npm install

# Get the built application from the first stage
COPY --from=build /app/dist dist

# Set runtime metadata
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
# CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

Isn't this solution bad since you end up installing dependencies twice in this case. Once in the `build` stage and 2nd in `runner` stage even if you install only production dependencies in runner stage.

I tried this solution and as expected I ended up with an image size of 1.18 GB.

Question 4: Which of the above solution is better to go for? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You intrinsically need two different sets of dependencies: you need the `devDependencies` to build the application but only the `dependencies` to run it.  Intrinsically you must run `npm install` or `npm ci` twice, once in development mode and once in production mode, and in different build stages.  The last Dockerfile you show should be fine (which suggests this question should be a duplicate of the one you link to) and I would expect it to produce a more reasonably-sized image.

Comment: isn't it kinda redundant to do both `npm ci` and `npm ci --production`. Since you can only use `npm install` and the app will run. There's no need to do `npm ci --production` in that case.

Comment: If you're concerned about image size, then you should separately run `npm ci --production` in a separate build stage to get only the runtime `dependencies` and not the `devDependencies`, then `COPY --from` the built application from the previous built stage.

Comment: That's one of the problems that I'm facing. `npm ci --production` alone won't work since I need typescript which is in devDependencies. If I do `npm ci --production` in a seperate stage then copy over the build then the `npm build` won't work.

Comment: The last Dockerfile you quote does this correctly: `npm ci` including dev dependencies in a first stage and run `npm build` there; and then in a second stage `npm ci --production` and `COPY` the results of the build from the first stage (but not its expanded `node_modules` tree).

Comment: Oh I see. I tried copying only the `build` folder from the `build stage` and then installing only production dependencies in the `runner` stage and it works. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

Use a container intermediate to install only packages for production

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS build

# Disable telemetry
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

WORKDIR /build

# Copy package and package-lock 
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# Clean install dependencies based package-lock
# Note: We also install dev deps as typeScript may be needed
RUN npm ci

# Copy files
# Use .dockerignore to avoid copying node_modules and others folders and files
COPY . .

# Build application
RUN npm run build

# =======================================
# Image generate dependencies production
# =======================================
FROM node:14-alpine AS dependencies

# Environment Production
ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /dependencies

# Copy package and package-lock 
COPY --from=build /build/package.json .
COPY --from=build /build/package-lock.json ./

# Clean install dependencies based package-lock
RUN npm ci --production

# =======================================
# Image distroless final
# =======================================
FROM gcr.io/distroless/nodejs:14

# Mark as prod, disable telemetry, set port
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV PORT 3000
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

WORKDIR /app

# Copy from build
COPY --from=build /build/next.config.js .
COPY --from=build /build/public/ ./public
COPY --from=build /build/.next ./.next
COPY --from=dependencies /dependencies/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 3000

# Run app command
CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you can use the base image https://github.com/ryanbekhen/feserve/pkgs/container/feserve as the production stage. This is an image that I made based on the complaints that occurred on the frontend. The base image is only around 8 MB, so it doesn't take up a lot of storage.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33651529)